# Trouble With SearchBar and Search Bar Controller Due to Depreciation of SearchDisplayController

Tags: json, swift

I would like some help with the search bar functionality.  I am stuck and not sure where to take it from here.  I am trying to update the tableview when search text word is contained in a recipe title.  I am not sure how to do this because of the depreciated searchDisplay controller.  Help would be appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

class Downloader {

class func downloadImageWithURL(_ url:String) -> UIImage! {

    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: url)!)
    return UIImage(data: data!)
}
}

class ViewController:       UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate{




@IBOutlet weak var recipeTable: UITableView!


// search functionality  Need help with my search functionality

   var filteredRecipes = [Recipe]()

func filterContentForSearch(searchText:String) {
    // need help here

    self.filteredRecipes = self.recipes.filter({(title:Recipe)  -> Bool in

        return (title.title!.lowercased().range(of: searchText.lowercased()) != nil)
    })
}

private func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearch(searchText: searchString)
    return true
}





//end search parameters


// tableview functionionalitys
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
        return filteredRecipes.count
    }else{
        return recipes.count
    }
   // recipeTable.reloadData()
}


// tableview functionalities
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! RecipeTableViewCell


  if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView{
    //get images from download
    DispatchQueue.main.async { () ->Void in
        cell.imageLabel.image = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(self.filteredRecipes[indexPath.row].imageUrl)
    }
        cell.recipeLabel.text = self.filteredRecipes[indexPath.row].title
    recipeTable.reloadData()

   }else{
    //get image from download

    DispatchQueue.main.async { () ->Void in
        cell.imageLabel.image = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(self.recipes[indexPath.row].imageUrl)

    }
    cell.recipeLabel.text = recipes[indexPath.row].title

    }
    //recipeTable.reloadData()
    return cell

}


// structs for json
struct Root : Decodable {
    let count : Int
    let recipes : [Recipe]
}

struct Recipe : Decodable { // It's highly recommended to declare Recipe in singular form
    let recipeId : String
    let imageUrl, sourceUrl, f2fUrl : String
    let title : String?
    let publisher : String
    let socialRank : Double
    let page : Int?
    let ingredients : [String]?
}

//recipes is array of Recipes
var recipes = [Recipe]() // array of recipes

//unfiltered recipes to put into search





fileprivate func getRecipes() {

    let jsonURL = "https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=264045e3ff7b84ee346eb20e1642d9d9"
    //.data(using: .utf8)!



    guard let url = URL(string: jsonURL) else{return}

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response , err) in
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode != 200 {
            print(response.statusCode)
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if let err = err{
                print("failed to get data from URL",err)
                return
            }
            guard let data = data  else{return}

            //print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)

                self.recipes = result.recipes

                //print(result.recipes)
                self.recipeTable.reloadData()
            }catch let jsonERR {
                print("Failed to decode",jsonERR)
            }
        }

        }.resume()

}



override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    //recipeTable.reloadData()

    //search bar

//filteredRecipes = recipes
    //call json object
    getRecipes()
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am trying to learn. Any pointers or tutorials you know of please link. @matt

Answer (score 0):

You could take this approach:

Add a Boolean variable to indicate whether searching or not

```
var searching: Bool = false
```

Use this for numberOfRowsInSection for the tableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searching {
        return filteredRecipes.count
    } else {
        return recipes.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! RecipeTableViewCell

    var recipe: Recipe

    if searching {
        recipe = filteredRecipes[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        recipe = recipes[indexPath.row]
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async { () ->Void in
        cell.imageLabel.image = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(recipe.imageUrl)
    }

    cell.recipeLabel.text = recipe.title

    return cell
}
```

And add this for the searchBar (set searching for other funcs like searchBarCancelButtonClicked)

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        searching = false
        filteredRecipes.removeAll()
        view.endEditing(true)
    } else {
        searching = true
        filteredRecipes = recipes.filter{$0.title.contains(searchBar.text!)}
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: i'm really new to working with searchBar. Do i need the searchBarCancelButtonClicked?  I set the searchBar delegate to self in the viewDidLoad function and changed my code to match yours.  The tableview however doesn't reload and it says the filteredRecipes goes unused in the searchbar function for filteredRecipes = recipes.filter{$0.title.contains(searchBar.text!)} @Wilson Desimini  (thanks for the answer btw) I'll checkmark it when i figure out what's wrong.

Comment: This actually did not work.  I will update my code when I get a chance to reflect the correct answer

Comment: You do need searchBarCancelButtonClicked unless you have a gesture recognizer in place to cancel the search. Sorry! Hope it helped, glad you found the right answer